# datagridview won't update

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have this datagridview:

[image: my datagrid]

using this procedure:

```
 alter proc [dbo].[verfornecex1] (@FILA INT )   as
 select idfornec,nome,conta,ativo from tbfornec
 where Nome is not null and IdFornec = @fila
 order by Nome
```

I have written this code:

```
SqlConnection conec2 = Tconex.Minifim();
DataSet grava = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
       SqlCommandBuilder constru9 = new SqlCommandBuilder(dap1);
       SqlCommand llena11 = new SqlCommand("verfornecex1", conec2);
       llena11.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       SqlParameter tpd = new SqlParameter("@fila", SqlDbType.Int);
       tpd.Value = vlz;
       llena11.Parameters.Add(tpd);
       dap1.SelectCommand = llena11;
       dap1.Fill(grava, "fabricante");
       DataRow dr3 = grava.Tables["fabricante"].NewRow();
       dr3["ativo"] = 1;
       dap1.Update(grava, "fabricante");
```

But something is wrong there. I use `DataSet` because `DataTable` doesn't make update.

Comment: Try running `dap.Fill` again after the update.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a connection to the database?, probably that is conec2, but just check it

I think you're missing a DataTable function?

```
SqlCommand llena11 = new SqlCommand("verfornecex",conec2);
SqlDataAdapter dap1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
dap1.SelectCommand = llena11;
DataTable grava = new DataTable();
dap1.Fill(grava, "fabricante");
dataGridView1.DataSource = grava;
dapt1.Update(grava, "fabricante");
```

Hope this helps a little...